# WP Rest API - Upload image to WP using Restsharp

Tags: wordpress, vb.net, restsharp

I have a problem uploading an image to Wordpress from a VB .NET project (using Restsharp). I create the client and the request for this, I added a header with the authorization, parameters...) but, when I execute the request, this response Status OK (200) but the image has not create in Wordpress.

I tried all this sentences, and no works:

**Test 1:**

```
Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient("http://domain-example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media")
client.Timeout = -1
Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic {base64code}")
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=b83jbtsfjbb2bkkso7s75m75il")
request.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Google-logo.jpg")
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
request.AddFile("file", "C:\temp\Google-logo.jpg")
request.AddParameter("title", "titleExample")
request.AddParameter("caption", "captionExample")
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode)
```

**Test 2:**

```
Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient("http://domain-example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media")
client.Timeout = -1
Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic {base64code}")
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=b83jbtsfjbb2bkkso7s75m75il")
request.AddParameter("title", "titleExample")
request.AddParameter("caption", "captionExample")
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = True
request.AddParameter("file", "C:\temp\Google-logo.png")
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode)
```

**Test 3:**

```
Dim client as RestClient = New RestClient("http://domain-example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media")
client.Timeout = -1
Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic {base64code}")
request.AddFileBytes("file", BytesImage, "C:\temp\Google-logo.jpg", "image/jpeg")
request.AddParameter("title", "tempFile")
request.AddParameter("caption", "tempFileCaption")
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
Console.WriteLine(response.Content)
```

**Test 4: In this example I not use RestSharp, I used the HttpWebRequest, and the same result**

```
Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest
Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse

myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://domain-example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media")

myReq.Method = "POST"
myReq.ContentType = "application/json"
myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:password")))
Dim myData As String = "c:\temp\Google-logo.jpg"
myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)
myResp = myReq.GetResponse
Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
Dim myText As String
myText = myreader.ReadToEnd
```

I tried to simulate the upload using Postman, but I can't.

I don't know why it's so hard to upload an image to Wordpress using REST...

Disclaimer:
[Also, this post doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269974/uploading-image-to-wordpress-media-using-restsharp)

Answer (score 1):

The following is from the [docs](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#uploading-files).

To add a file to the request you can use the `RestRequest` function called `AddFile`. The main function accepts the `FileParameter` argument:

```
request.AddFile(fileParameter);
```

You can instantiate the file parameter using `FileParameter.Create` that accepts a bytes array or `FileParameter.FromFile`, which will load the file from disk.

There are also extension functions that wrap the creation of `FileParameter` inside:

```
// Adds a file from disk
AddFile(parameterName, filePath, contentType);

// Adds an array of bytes
AddFile(parameterName, bytes, fileName, contentType);

// Adds a stream returned by the getFile function
AddFile(parameterName, getFile, fileName, contentType);
```

Remember that `AddFile` will set all the necessary headers, so please don't try to set content headers manually. Your code sets a lot of content headers, and it's unnecessary, and might be breaking your requests.

You can always use https://requestbin.com and send your requests there to inspect the content of those requests, so you can see if they match the expected request format.

Answer (score 1):

In test 1, remove or comment out this line of code:

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is activate the [JWT authentication plugin for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/). By default, Wordpress avoid any POST call, the basic authentication doesn't work.

So, once activated the JWT (following the process), you must create a Token (using POST to the JWT endpoint) and put the Token in the POST process to create anything (posts, media, etc.)